# Rendering Multiple Leaflet Maps on Single tabPanel Crashes Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to render multiple leaflet plot on one tabpanel of my shiny app and that is causing the app/R studio to crash.

Individually each of the leaflet plot is rendered correctly (i.e., displaying only one at a time) but not when I try all of them together.

I am doing something like this (map1, map2 and all are leaflet maps)

```
tabPanel("Leaflet Maps", 
               leafletOutput("map1", width = 800, height = 500), br(),
               leafletOutput("map2", width = 800, height = 500), br().
               leafletOutput("map3", width = 800, height = 500), br(),
               leafletOutput("map4", width = 800, height = 500), br(),
               leafletOutput("map5", width = 800, height = 500)
             )
...
...
...

output$map1<- renderLeaflet({
   ... lines of code creating leaflet map
})
```

Has anyone faced this problem before or know what it is I could be doing wrong? I will provide more code snippet from my app if needed.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Does it crash when you render 2, or only when rendering 5?

Comment: It is somewhat random and I still don't see a pattern as to rendering exactly how many will crash the app. It mostly doesn't crash with 2 and since I have plotted all of them separately, I know that there is no problem with the maps.

Comment: Does it crash when you use external browser (and try different browser)?

Comment: Rstudio crashes if I run the app from there and the browser crashes when I start the app in the browser. I am using launch.browser = TRUE and it launches by default in google chrome. How can I select some different browser to launch? Thanks!

Comment: When you launch you app in external browser, RStudio will have a console output that says something like `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3449`. Copy the url and open it in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link (drive.google.com/open?id=0Byn3NtvHyj_JT3ZRM3JzSlhXTlE) to get sample app that tries to render multiple leaflet plots. I've also included the required input data.

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Still looking for some help on this. Anyone?

Comment: Please put additional information in your question, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37711143/edit